# How to Prevent caching the HTML page in GWT Application

Tags: html, caching, gwt, smartgwt

I have an application developed using `GWT & SmartGWT`. Currently the host page is getting cached in browser which i don't want to do this.I want to prevent the host page(html Page) not to be cached in browser.I tried by adding some tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

How to achieve this.Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Below is Filter class, to prevent caching *nochache* files from GWT compiler. Add your index.html to if statement and activate Filter in your web.xml

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * {@link Filter} to add cache control headers for GWT generated files to ensure
 * that the correct files get cached.
 * 
 * @author See Wah Cheng
 * @created 24 Feb 2009
 */
public class GWTCacheControlFilter implements Filter {

 public void destroy() {
 }

 public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
 }

 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,
   ServletException {

  HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
  String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();

  if (requestURI.contains(".nocache.")) {
   Date now = new Date();
   HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
   httpResponse.setDateHeader("Date", now.getTime());
   // one day old
   httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", now.getTime() - 86400000L);
   httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
   httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  }

  filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Thomasz for your reply..i was able to achieve this on doing server side changes..i added filter in the server side..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: thanks flo-ferox..i tried this but didn't solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you have a problem with cached "host page", not with cached javascript?

If indeed there is a problem with html page, you can add necessary headers in your web server.

If problem is with caching javascript files with "*nochache*"names, standard solution is to add filter to your web.xml.

Comment: thanks tomasz for your reply..yes its with html page..when i hit the application first time its making a html call and getting response with 200 status but when second time when i am making a call ,getting response with 302

Comment: So find "gwt nocache filter" end extend it to add appropiate headers to index.html.